# How to find mood from song

Tags: python, python-2.6

My actual work is to find mood of song i.e. either a sad song or a
happy song. I try to find frequencies of mp3 file with fft but it just
give the frequencies of small files, like ringtone. Can you guide me
which audio feature, such as pitch, timbre, loudness, tempo, could be
use to find mood of a songs which are in current playlist? And is it
neccessary for this to find frequencies?
And I am working in python 2.6 with module tkinter.

Comment: Question is very broad..

Comment: I think you can write a full dissertation about this subject and you expect it in a single stackoverflow answer?

Comment: Even if the FFT gave you the exact notes (e.g. you get the output as a MIDI file) you have to understand at the very least the *harmony* of the piece to understand if they combine to make a happy or sad piece, and this isn't a simple task.

Comment: D minor is the saddest chord.

Comment: If you're asking SO, you're not ready for this. Go read the appropriate research.

Comment: This is quite interesting. Looks like a real question to me

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way - find the lyrics on the web and train a classifier to determine if the lyrics are sad or happy. Even if you wont get good enough accuracy this way you could use it as part of the solution in conjunction with the harmony/melody analysis.

Answer (score 1):

check [this](http://www.experienceproject.com/music_search.php)

... well all I found was that site which shows music for a specific mood you want. Means music is tagged I guess. So I think you can't say when a song is happy / sad / angry just because of its frequencies or speed... there are some ballads that are REALLY nice and happy, but also a lot of sad ones... same for other pop music, there is music that sounds great, makes you dance and freak out, but the context / lyrics are sad. It also depends on so many things...

1. The listener (what does he like, what does he feel for a special kind of music, how is his interpretation for a special song?)
2. The song itself (how is it made, lyrics, speed and who is listening to it?)
3. The singer. Do you like him? Do you like the voice(s) you hear? Is the singers tone a tone which means "sad" for you? Or does it sound "happy" for you? Depends on what your ears have learned!
4. The people around you. You listen to a song... would you start dancing because it sounds happy for you, even everyone around you cries? I doubt that! ;)

...

So I could write my next two years about that and we would end in some discussions about psychology and the effect of adverts / marketing, you and myself!

The best solution, and how many others do it, is ... tag your songs... get a big database and thats it! I don't think that you can find a way to make this automatic.

Oh I forgot to say, a song mostly is like a book... you have the "here I am part" ... the "what goes wrong" part and then the conclusion how to solve the issue... so lets define that as happy? sad? :D Depends, depends!

Here is a page where songs get analyzed if they are hits or not. Maybe you should contact them and ask them how they do it. [uplaya](http://uplaya.com/)

Try out this -> [Moodbar](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Moodbar) (Ubuntu / Linux)
It's a mood bar which shows you the mood of a current position of a song. Maybe you could work with that.

But in fact, it is a big thing what you are looking for, and yes, might take ages to get a good result! :D

PS: I wish you the best! :)